# how to add wordpress user from external remote form

Tags: php, wordpress, remoteapi

i have two websites, websiteA is a worpdress website, and websiteB is a simple php website.
i want to link the two website. i have a form in websiteB and i want it to be able to add users in websiteA.
i already tried the code below , it creates user but redirect to websiteA while i am in websiteB:

```
<form name="myForm" action="http://ipSiteA/wp-admin/user-new.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="createuser">
<input type="hidden" name="user_login" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="mail@gmail.Com">
<input type="hidden" name="pass1" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="pass2" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="role" value="seller">
<input type="hidden" name="createuser" value="Ajouter un utilisateur">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce_create-user" value="815389c6d9">
<input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/wp-admin/user-new.php">
<input type="submit" name="create" value="Creer">
```

is there any other solution using remote apli for example? if not, is there a way to not be redirected to websiteA?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a hook on the registration method on the site, where you need it. Open your `functions.php` in your websiteB. This is in your theme directory. If there is no file like this, create one.

Put this into that file:

```
add_action('register_form', 'my_register_form');
function my_register_form() {
    //Redirects the user to an URL
    header("Location: http://example.com/");
    die();
}
```

Of course, you need to write your URL instead of the example.com.

**[Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form)** is the referenc of the `register_form` action.

Comment: but websiteB is not a wordpress site, have i to put your code in websiteB?

Comment: You want to register your user into the wordpress site right?

Comment: Ok, so the solution above is correct. You need to put this snippet of code, in your wordpress site. ipSiteA. And `header("Location: http://ipSiteB/");`